# primefaces file upload not working

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces

I have the following code, running on jboss eap 6.1:

```
 <h:form id="SatelliteListForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
<p:fileUpload id="datamodelImport" mode="advanced" auto="true" disabled="#{empty satelliteController.selected}" fileUploadListener="#{satelliteController.importDatamodel}" update=":messages" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(csv)$/"/>
```

web.xml contains this:

```
   <filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

pom.xml have this:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

the problem? it doesn't not work. The UI seems to be working fine, but the file upload listener is not called. 
Using search BalucC suggest to debug http communication. Done, it is not the browser fault. Then he suggest to debug the decode method of the corresponding primefaces class. Done. In the following class 
org.primefaces.component.fileupload.CommonsFileUploadDecoder
he do this check:
if(multipartRequest != null) // keep going, otherwise stop

in my case that variable is null. I can't understand why. The generated html code correctly contains the enctype.

BalusC suggest that something could happen during request processing. I'm using atmosphere, but it uses another servlet to communicate. Also he is complaining for quite some time about comet support (someday I will fix that). Don't know if it matters.

What else can I check?
It's irritating that something so simple as file upload is wasting so much of my time...

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hi!! Were you able to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

did you try to add the following parameter to your web.xml?

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
    <param-value>commons</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I had the same behaviour until I added these context param

Regards

Michael